# Android SDK Tools was not installing on My Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-sdk-tools

When i was trying to Updating my tools, It was asking every time after downloading the tools(while Installing Updates) the pic as show as,

[image: SDK Manager Failed to Install]

when i was press Yes , Continuously asking again and again
when i press No,Stops every thing.

[image: Manager Log]

How can i fix this issue, Any Have solution for this ?

Comment: run the sdk manager as administrator

Comment: i tried as administrator also got issue again and cleared Temp folder also nothing better i got.

Comment: try to do like this   ----  Make a copy of the \tools folder, name it something like \copy. So you should have c:\android-sdk-windows\copy. Now run android.bat from the \copy folder with Admin privileges. This should prevent the issue with items currently being open in the \tools folder.

Comment: nothing worked for this time , i was downloaded new version of Bundle from Android Developer site- Finally i felt this is best way to away wasting time on this. I don't know why Google-Android wasn't  providing Technical support for this issue. B'coz its happening around the Globe.

Answer (score 1):

Close all windows explorer and run `eclipse.exe` or `sdkmanager.exe` as **administrator**.

Comment: Again it shows the same window and  asking Same thing..any other choices to prevent that @johntheripp3r

Comment: @KlynCrishnan Restart the computer and do the same. Your command prompt and adb.exe is locking the directory.